# JavaScript not working in Random Quotes Generator

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, multidimensional-array

I'm doing this project where I will have 100 or so quotes that will randomly show up when the user clicks on the button. It will also display the name of the quote's author, which is also a link to their website/wikipedia page.

When I open this file in the browser, everything works fine except the author does not display as a link. I tried putting my code into codepen and the link shows up but the fadeIn effect does not work. I'm going to have this on my wordpress website and when I uploaded it there, the links did not show up!

I've been trying to figure this out for days and I'm completely stuck! Could someone please look over my code and tell me if they see what's wrong? I'm self taught and still a beginner so I'm really interested in figuring this out! Thank you.

Here's the JS (let me know if you need me to post the HTML and CSS):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var qList = [{

    quote: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ut vivamus nulla cras wisi, consectetuer id sed leo tortor, et est et imperdiet vel. Vestibulum proin ante sit, risus odio consectetuer fermentum. Mus quisque eget orci in, platea fringilla aliquet euismod, pellentesque erat sapien ad. Vestibulum interdum ac arcu, rutrum dolor etiam at wisi. Eget bibendum amet vitae, cum est metus pellentesque, metus aenean tortor consequat, habitasse vel aliquam pulvinar in. Et libero ut est pede, aute mollis lectus etiam semper, bibendum sed urna non porta, mus bibendum eu vel. Arcu nunc arcu risus, quisque assumenda leo natoque sodales.",
    auth: "Id Ante",
    site: "http://www.google.com"
   }, 

   {

    quote: "Felis commodo sed et, erat vel elit purus. Neque enim sed condimentum placerat, nulla eu consequat eu. Fusce diam eleifend libero eget, pellentesque molestias aliquam nec, egestas morbi nunc justo. Arcu platea nunc turpis, sit fringilla iaculis turpis nec, ut fusce lacus dis, porta accumsan eget viverra feugiat. Metus quisque aliquet mus, quam dictum ipsum fringilla.",
    auth: "Maris Nunc",
    site: "http://www.google.com"
  },

  {

    quote: "Enim erat gravida at id, lacinia aliquam viverra vel vitae, felis nascetur quam mauris, dolor aenean eget morb",
    auth: "Ick Vrouw",
    site: "http://www.google.com"
   },

   {

    quote: "Aliquam hendrerit neque a ornare tristique. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aliquam convallis justo tristique nisi tincidunt pellentesque. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.",
    auth: "Sed Librio",
    site: "http://www.google.com"
   },

   {

    quote: "Fusce in volutpat urna. Mauris tellus felis, semper et scelerisque quis, tristique eu lacus. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Proin quis fringilla justo. Morbi eu tristique neque.Etiam pellentesque tincidunt dui, in congue urna bibendum non. Mauris dignissim nisi nec ante accumsan tincidunt. Integer lorem urna, pharetra vitae aliquam id, consequat eget felis",
    auth: "Een Boterham",
    site: "http://www.google.com"
   },

   {

    quote: "Morbi arcu nunc, aliquam sit amet dictum ac, eleifend a sapien. Suspendisse nec eros non dui condimentum commodo ut a puru",
    auth: "Egestas nunc ac eu. Eleifend quisque amet hymenaeos eget, massa lorem nibh etiam suscipit ullamcorper, aenean aenean. Nascetur a, ultricies vitae suspendisse in, et sit. Ut non urna, quis urna litora cras luctus, amet at congue tincidunt eget. Morbi volutpat posuere, id facilisis velit. Donec condimentum felis etiam ipsum volutpat curabitur.",
    site: "http://www.google.com"

   }];

  function getRandomNum(min, max) { 

    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
  }


  var button = $(".btn-primary");

  function getQuotes () {

    var quoteNum = getRandomNum(0, qList.length);
    $(".btn-primary").text("Next Pep Talk");
    $("#thequote").text(qList[quoteNum].quote);
    $("#theauth").text(qList[quoteNum].auth);
    $("#theauth").attr("href", qList[quoteNum].site);

  }


   getQuotes();


  function fading () { 

      $(".fade").fadeIn("fast");

    }


  fading();


  button.click(function() {

    getQuotes();
    fading();

  });


});
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<html dir="ltr" lang="en-US">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="quotegen.css">
<title>Quote Example</title>





</head>

<body>

    <div class="quote-generator">

        <h2 class="text-primary text-center">The Quote Generator</h2>



            <div class="quote-text" id="quoteplace" class="row center- block">

                <p id="thequote" class="fade" class="col center-block">.</p>


            </div>

            <div class="writer" class="center-block">

                <i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i><br >

                <p id="theauth" class="fade" class="col center-block"></p><br /> <br />

            </div>



        <div class="center-block">

        <button type="button" id="button" class="btn btn-primary center-block">Next Pep Talk</button><br /><br />

        </div>

        <div class="quote-description">The Quote Generator is a project by XXX<br />



        </div>




    </div>  


        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="quotegen.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


</body>

</html>
```

And here's the CSS if you want it too:

```
.quote-generator { 
margin: 50px auto; 
width: 65%; 
text-align: center; 
border:1px black dotted;
padding:50px;

}

.quote-generator input[type="submit"], button {
 cursor: pointer;
margin-top: 30px;
overflow: visible;
border: 1px solid #f05525;
background: white;
font-family:"Raisonne Demibold","Century Gothic", Verdana, sans-serif; 
font-size: 130%;
letter-spacing: 2px;
text-transform: uppercase;
padding: 10px 30px;
color: #f05525;
} 

.quote-generator input[type="submit"], button:hover {
color: black;
border: 1px solid black;
}

.quote-generator a { 
border-bottom: 1px dotted #f05525;
padding-bottom: 2px;
}

.quote-generator a:hover {
border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
color: black;
}


.quote-generator h2 { 
font-family:"Raisonne Demibold", "Cardo" "Century Gothic", Verdana, sans-serif; 
font-size: 250%; 
margin: 0 0 50px 0;
color: #f05525;
}

.writer {
font-style: italic;
font-variant: normal;
font-weight: 500;
letter-spacing: 1px;
font-size: 80%;
}

.quote-text {

border-left: 1px dotted black;
border-right: 1px dotted black;
font-size: 130%;
line-height: 145%;
margin: 0 0 20px;
padding: 30px;
text-align: left;   



}

.quote-description {
font-style: italic;
font-variant: normal;
font-weight: 500;
font-size: 90%;
letter-spacing: 1px;
margin-bottom: 20px;    
}


#theauth {
margin-left:15px;
}
```

Comment: Plz show us the HTML/CSS to and if you can make fiddle/codepen.

Comment: Here's a link to the codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Jdwyrb

Comment: now that I see your fiddle, yeah, like I thought... #theauth, in order to have an HREF assigned, will need to be a link.   You can have it remain a P element, but then have to use an onclick to handle the hyperlinking... if that makes sense.  see my answer below for my fiddle example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

don't see your full HTML, but make sure that

```
$("#theauth").text(qList[quoteNum].auth);
$("#theauth").attr("href", qList[quoteNum].site);
```

refers to link element, not a div or other element...

heres a fiddle that has an

```
<a id="theauth"></a>
```

that then allows us to set the HREF dynamically.  good luck with it.

heres a [fiddle I did](http://jsfiddle.net/tamak/axp7th7w/1/)

Comment: YESS!! That worked!!! Thank you SO much! That makes so much sense now that you pointed that out. I'm so happy, thanks again.

Comment: @JTSparks - no problem. vote for the answer since it helped? thanks